# Copy fields/column structure in access

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-access, vbscript

I am needing to figure out a way write a query or code to copy field additions to tables in an Access mdb reference database to an (older) copy of that database that may not be updated with the new columns/fields.   Basically I will loop through the tables in the reference database, then loop through the columns in each table and add the missing ones.

I have the code to loop through the tables, and the columns but I am hoping there is a simple query I can execute to copy the missing column from the reference table to the table in the older copy of the database.  If not, maybe some help with getting the column structure, so I can do an alter table query to update with the exact structure of the col.   Been googling all afternoon and only found examples of copying data from table to table....

Comment: You could write an `ALTER TABLE` statement and then call `OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` to execute it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - Yes, however I will first need to figure out how to get information about the existing column & that's a big part of my question.   Seems there are two possibilities:
1.)  Easily copy the column in a nice compact & slick query

2.)  Glean info about the column, then use that to write an ALTER TABLE statement to update the target table.   In this case, I need to reliably figure out the existing column's parameters

Comment: You should be able to use the `OleDbConnection.GetSchema` method to get the information you need.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - The thing that sucks here is that the datatype returned can map to several values.   For instance, Datatype 130 can be "LongText" or "VarChar" - so you don't know if it's a memo field or a text field.   Best I can tell, Memo has a CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH of 0 instead of a positive number.   Who thought it was a good idea to have "NATIVEDATATYPE"s be duplicated across more than one actual type???    This is why I was hoping there was some simple SQL that could just copy the field :)

Comment: There's also a `GetOleDbSchemaTable` method or the like.  Does that give better info?  I guess the thing to remember here is that your database is being treated as an OLE DB data source so you're getting OLE DB metadata, not Access metadata.  To get more specific info then you may have to use ADO or DAO, or maybe even Office Automation.